# Notwithstanding the above

Tags: word-meaning

It is about the word **"above"** in the term: *"Notwithstanding the above"*
Would one interpret the "above" literally?

Example:

***Tommorow I think it will rain. Or even worse.***

***Notwithstanding the above, I will go to circus***

Does the "above" relate to the sentence before, or above in this case? Or is it just a fixed term?

Comment: It is used mainly in formal documents (e.g. legal). "Above" refers to sentences earlier in the text.  Your example would be atypical.  Compare "abovementioned".

Comment: If you're thinking of using ***the above*** to reference something that's "literally" above the speaker (such as storm clouds) the answer is *No, you can't do that.* You'd also be very unlikely to use it figuratively in any spoken context, since it's essentially a "text-oriented" usage. Finally, you wouldn't use it if the text you're referring back to is just a couple of immediately preceding short sentences because it's too ponderously formal. In your example the natural idiomatic choice would simply be ***Despite that,...***

Comment: In the text I wrote, I was referring a whole paragraph, whether I could implement an API on a single client or on a server. Under that paragraph I wrote analogously: "Notwithstanding the above, the traffic generated by a single client should be very low." The text got an academic approach, so I am fine with something that formal, I just would like to know, whether the **"above"** is literally referring to what was written above.

Comment: TRomano is correct - this phrase was used often in handwritten letters to call back to what was said previously.  It still survives in formal/academic writing.  It's worth noting that the text in question may not be immediately or directly above the reference to "above" due to formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments indicate, using *the above* to refer to something that was previously stated is only used in written English, where the previous sentence appears physically higher on the page (but it could actually be on a different page due to formatting). You would need to say this differently in spoken English, such as replacing *the above* with *that* (which more generally refers to something that was previously said or referenced).